# Executar videos do youtube em uma web view

Tags: java, android

Vídeos do YouTube não são reproduzidos em Uma web view no Android 4.0, mas no 6.0 os vídeos são executados normalmente. Já pesquisei bastante sobre esse tema, porém não encontrei nenhuma resposta prática para o meu baixíssimo conhemento sobre desenvolvimento Android.
Se alguém está apto a me ajudar a como reproduzir vídeos do YouTube em uma web view, peço que seja bastante claro, por favor.
a seguir meu código:

```
    pagina.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
    pagina.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    pagina.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);


    pagina.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            public  void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)    

            {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon); 
                Barra.setText(url);
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}});
    pagina.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){
            @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)
            {
                DownloadManager.Request request =new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));                
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();final String filename =URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);          
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);               
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Download", filename);DownloadManager dm =(DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);          
                dm.enqueue(request);Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);             
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);    
                intent.setType("*/*");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download iniciado",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}});

    proximo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (pagina.canGoForward())
                {
                    pagina.goForward();}

                else
                { 
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não há paginas para avançar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();   

                }}});


    Ir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                pagina.loadUrl(Barra.getText().toString());}});


    voltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (pagina.canGoBack())
                {
                    pagina.goBack();}
                else
                { 
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não há paginas para voltar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }}});       
    reload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                pagina.reload();
                    };});}}
```

Comment: Jefferson, pode ser algo na webview do SO. Te aconselho a embutir um navegador em tua aplicação para que o comportamento sempre seja o mesmo independente da versão do android. Olha o link desse projeto eu uso muito ele e quebra um galho https://crosswalk-project.org/

Comment: Obrigado pelo conselho Hiago.